# Where is the XML parsing error (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, gradle

this error occured some times already, and most of the times it just disappered with an update.
When I try to run my little app, Android Studio says: 
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users...\AndroidStudioProjects\Getraenkerechner\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[14,16]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app

This is the content of the AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Support"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WaterCalc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Any idea what the problem could be? 
I tried installing a new gradle version but that didn't help..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `>>` should be `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `manifest` tag. Of course don't forget to change the package name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <!-- put here the code you posted -->
</manifest>
```

To learn more on the Manifest file read the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).

In your case the right Manifest format would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Support"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".WaterCalc"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No, I didn't copy it because stackoverflow said there were errors in my code or something.. :D. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @SilentSniper I updated the answer copy and paste the second XML in your application Manifest...

Comment: It works now, you saved me a lot of time :) Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!